# Healthcare.gov PlanFinder API v2.0 still accepting requests?

Tags: data.gov, api, healthcare-finder-api

I would like to get 2014 off-exchange plan data from the Healthcare.gov PlanFinder API.  I have read (on this site) that the current version v3.0 does not accept insurance effective dates before 1/1/2015, and that v2.0 of the API, which is deprecated, is the version to use to collect 2014 data.  I have recently tried to use v2.0, using the sample query provided on the site, and receive a response about the page not being found and then some text about needing to at least fill in e-mail and phone number.

I have successfully used v3.0 of the API and did not need to provide an email address.  I would like to know if it is still possible to get 2014 off-exchange data from the site.

Thank you.